# Assertion failure in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, uicollectionview

I have some images hosted online that are being parsed into `UIImageView`s in my `UICollectionViewCell`s. When I enter in and out of the view, I frequently get a crash and the following error in the debugger :

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2/UICollectionView.m:3870
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 items before the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1839702d8 0x19563c0e4 0x183970198 0x184824ed4 0x188a74348 0x100150300 0x100117c4c 0x100117d88 0x18332f010 0x1848571c4 0x1847a8604 0x1847981cc 0x184859f28 0x101410f94 0x101415c28 0x1839277f8 0x1839258a0 0x1838512d4 0x18d2a76fc 0x18844ef40 0x10011a1d4 0x195ce6a08)
```

What is the cause of this error and how should I get rid of it?

**UPDATE**

I observed that the crash occurs when i segue to the `collectionView`, and quickly return back before any of the cells load.. but it shouldn't crash because of this reason. How do I fix this?

here is my cellForIndex.. Method

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        // Configure the cell
        let book = self.books[indexPath.row]
        let coverImage = book.coverImage
        if coverImage == nil {
            book.fetchCoverImage({ (image, error) -> Void in
                collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
            })
        } else {
            let imageView = cell.imageView
            imageView.image = book.coverImage
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and look at the call stack to determine where your problem is - show your code

Comment: i tried but it wouldn't crash this time. and that error in my question is actually an NSException that was thrown.. it would happen when i would abruptly exit out the collection view screen before anything loaded up.. well thats what i observed @Paulw11

Comment: Show more your code please. cellAtIndex, ...

Comment: I think the problem is this block `{ (image, error) -> Void in
                collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
            }` is being called when you exit out the collection. Can you try check `collectionView != nil`, or use a flag if exit out or something to break this block?

Comment: can you provide that code in an answer?

Comment: Do you try to delete any cell somewhere?

Comment: you still available? @anhtu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to break block of reloadItems

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        // Configure the cell
        let book = self.books[indexPath.row]
        let coverImage = book.coverImage
        if coverImage == nil {
            book.fetchCoverImage({ (image, error) -> Void in
                if collectionView != nil { // <--- something like this. I'm not sure. Just take the idea: try to check before reload.
                    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
                }
            })
        } else {
            let imageView = cell.imageView
            imageView.image = book.coverImage
        }
        return cell
    }
```